# Show $\nabla f=A\nabla g$ by chain rule

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, chain-rule, scalar-fields

Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ an invertible matrix, $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be smooth, and define $g:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ by $$g(Ax)=f(x),$$ i.e., if I set the variable of $g$ as $y$, $g(y)=f(A^{-1}y).$

Then, show $\nabla f=A\nabla g$ using chain rule.

---

Where do I mistake ?

Let $D$ represent the derivative.

\begin{align}
D_y g(y)
&=D_y(f(A^{-1}y))\\
&=(D_x f)(A^{-1}y)\cdot D_y(A^{-1}y)\\
&=(D_x f)(x)\cdot A^{-1} ,
\end{align}
and since $D_y g(y)=\nabla g(y)$, $(D_x f)(x)=\nabla f(x)$, I get $$\nabla g=\nabla f\cdot A^{-1}$$ and then $$\nabla f=(\nabla g)A.$$

Comment: Simple. The gradient is the *transpose* of the derivative matrix. But the formula is wrong, and sloppy to boot because it omits the points at which the gradients are evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the identity you were asked to prove is false unless $A$ is symmetric. For example try $g(x,y) = x+y$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $f(x,y) = g(x + y, y) = x + 2y$ and $\nabla f = \left[1, 2\right]^T$. Since $\nabla g = \left[1,1\right]^T$, notice that $\nabla f = A^T \nabla g \neq A \nabla g$.

---

The following:
$$D_yg(y) = \nabla g(y)$$
is not correct, though it's a very common confusion. The left-hand side is the *covariant* Jacobian/differential, and is $1 \times 2$ row vector. The right-hand side is the *contravariant* gradient vector and is $2\times 1$ column vector.

They are related by the definition of the gradient: $\nabla g$ is the unique vector which satisfies
$$\langle \nabla g, v\rangle = \left[Dg\right]v$$
for every  vector $v$. For the standard Euclidean inner product it follows that $\nabla g = [Dg]^T$.

The correct conclusion of your proof is thus
$$
\begin{align*}
D_y g &= \left[D_x f\right] A^{-1}\\
\left[D_y g\right] A &= D_x f\\
A^T \nabla g &= \nabla f.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\n{\nabla}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\qquad\implies\qquad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Define the vector $w=A\cdot x$ and note that $A$ does not need to be invertible; it might even be rectangular.

Given a scalar quantity that can be expressed as a function of **either** $\,x$ or $w$
$$\eqalign{
h &= f(x) = g(w) \\
}$$
first calculate its differential using the $g(w)$ function
$$\eqalign{
dh &= \gradLR gw \cdot dw \;=\; \gradLR gw \cdot \LR{A \cdot dx} \;=\; \CLR{A^T \cdot \grad gw} \cdot dx \\
}$$
then using the $f(x)$ function
$$\eqalign{
dh &= \c{\gradLR fx} \cdot dx \qiq \grad fx = A^T \cdot \grad gw
}$$

---

In the above derivation, $(a\cdot b)$ denotes the dot product.